# Inexpensive AC charger for iPod 3rd gen / 4th gen

Tags: ipod, charging, usb

I have a couple of iPod Touches, a 3rd generation and a 4th generation. I would like to get an AC adaptor so that I can plug them into the wall to charge. The Apple charger is $30, which seems quite expensive to me (the cheapest 3rd-party USB charging units are just a few dollars).

Is there an inexpensive AC charging unit for these iPods? Or am I stuck in the Apple happy place?

As a bonus, I've also got a Garmin Nuvi GPS unit that would be nice to charge with the same device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use any USB charger of decent build quality, as long as they follow the USB spec. Emphasis on decent build quality, you get what you pay for sometimes. The Apple charger has the added advantage of working with other Apple plug adapters the MacBooks use, like the travel kit and those longer cords. Plus they look nice ;)

If you're looking for quality-but-thrifty, try finding unused USB ports on other devices, such as the Xbox 360.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right; I was under the impression that Apple devices did fancy, nonstandard things that made them not work with standard USB chargers. However, I bought a cheap Zune charger for $5 and it works fine on an iPod Touch 3rd gen.

Answer (score 0):

For really cheap chargers that work try [DealExtreme](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.33892), I have one I used to charge an IPhone.